# How to plot a map in R without geographic coordinates?

Tags: r, google-maps, maps

I have a data set with some meteorological stations. I have to locations of these stations given as locations in a grid that is used for estimation of some models, i.e., they have x and y values with ranges of around (0,600) for x and (0,500) for y. If I plot them, the "map" looks like this:

[image: like this].

Now, I would like to have a real map of Europe under these points. How can I do this?

I have some sort of IDs that I could partially match to a data base from the World Meteorological Organization which allowed me to get the longitudes and latitudes for a subset of these stations (around 15 % are missing, however). If I plot those on a real map, using for example the maps package for R, I get the locations on a map which looks like this:

[image: which looks like this].

However, for some stations in my data set, I do not have IDs given, so I can not match them to the true coordinates. The second plot thus contains ca 15% less stations than the first one, but I would like to show all points from the first plot in a real map (as given by the second plot). As mentioned, I thus need a way to get from the x-y-locations to the true geographical locations, or a way to transform a map such that it matches the first plot.

It is impossible to get the missing true locations, so my question is how I can get a map under the points given by the x and y locations in the grid.

Comment: I don't understand; why is your second link not the answer to the question? Is that what you're trying to create? Is it a different set of points?

Comment: The second plot contains less points than the first one, as I do not have IDs given for around 15% of the stations, for those I only have the x-y-locations in the grid. I have edited the original post accordingly

Comment: You can use the subset where you have both your x/y and its long/lat to get a transformation: presumably there's some a, b, c, d such that `a * x + b = long` and `c * y + d = lat`, so linear regression on those two would tell you, at which point you can calculate long and lat for your missing values. If you're not sure how to do that, please show a sample of your matched long/lat/x/y data (using something like `dput(head(yourdata, 10))` preferably) and I'll show an example

Comment: Is the true underlying transformation really linear? But thanks, I will try this!

Comment: Whether the transformation is linear depends on what the `x` and `y` represent. It's certainly possible they're in some alternative coordinate system that don't correspond to longitude and latitude. But your question assumes you'd be able to plot a standard (x = longitude, y = latitude) map of Europe "under" the points, which means that their relative positions must be the same. Make sense? You'll be able to check if the transformation is linear by plotting at the relationship between x and longitude for the points you do know

Comment: If you plot the long<->x and lat<->y plots and they are not linear, they must at least be monotonic. (Otherwise, you could have a point with higher y that was south of a point with lower y- meaning the coordinates would have no meaning at all!) At that point, you can use `approx` to perform interpolation.

Comment: Ok, thanks! In the meanwhile, I was able to find a data set that contains the missing longitude-latitude information (at least most of it), so I do not need to transform / interpolate the x-y values / map locations. Thanks for all comments!